# .NET interop Excel to HTML

Tags: .net, interop

I'm using interop to convert .xls files to HTML:

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
    CreateExcel(datetime, path);

string inputFileName = path + datetime.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")+ ".xls";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xls = null;
try
{
    excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    object trueObject = true;
    excel.Visible = false;
    excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    xls = excel.Workbooks.Open(inputFileName, missing, trueObject, missing,
    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
    missing, missing, missing);
    object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml;
    System.Collections.IEnumerator wsEnumerator =
    excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.GetEnumerator();
    int i = 1;
    while (wsEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsCurrent =
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wsEnumerator.Current;
        String outputFile = path + datetime.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")+".html";
        wsCurrent.SaveAs(outputFile, format, missing, missing, missing,
        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        ++i;
    }
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
{
}
finally
{
    excel.Application.Quit();
    excel.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
    excel = null;
}
```

And in the end I get HTML files, without "styles". For example, the document loses all colors that the Excel file had. What am I missing?

Comment: 1) Add `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` to the top of your file and your code will be cleaner. 2) A foreach loop will do the iterating for you and you are not using the `i` counter. 3) Don't silently suppress exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export Excel spreadsheet to HTML table with INLINE CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436370/how-to-export-excel-spreadsheet-to-html-table-with-inline-css)

Comment: @PaulSweatte - I don't believe so

Answer (score 0):

For me, that worked perfectly

```
Dim excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
xls = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Users\A\Desktop\$R39M2VD\Nouveau Feuille Microsoft Office Excel.xlsx")
xls.SaveAs("D:\Users\A\Desktop\exported.html", XlFileFormat.xlHtml)
```