# How to export Excel spreadsheet to HTML table with INLINE CSS?

Tags: html, css, excel

I'd like to know how to get the table in my spreadsheet into html format without all the microsoft specific code.  Our webpage is hosted elsewhere which means I don't have access to the `<head>` part of our pages.  We can only insert content into the `<body>`.  I just want the table to retain the same fonts, borders and formatting with any and all CSS styling included directly in the table code not elsewhere.

**EDIT:**

It actually appears to work if I put the CSS classes in the `<body>` of my document.  Is that legal?  I thought those were supposed to be defined in the `<head>`???

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
table.mytable {
border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
font-size: 12px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have found that copying in Excel and pasting into the Live View in Dreamweaver creates much cleaner html than saving as html in your spreadsheet.  You are still left with a bajillion CSS classes that you have to edit out but it's at least it's a step closer.

If you get an error message whilst pasting a large table in Dream Weaver see [this page](http://www.jdhodges.com/blog/dreamweaver-document-too-large-copy-past/).

**FINAL EDIT:**

Before you export your table to any html editor go through ALL of the cells in your table with the format painter.  Using this tool make sure you paint the format of every similarly formatted cell.  That way you won't get a million different CSS classes for cells that should have a particular format.  It will make your life a hell of a lot easier particularly if your table is large and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "illegal" to place the style codes on the body, but defenitly not web friendly

What usualy goes in the head is a pointer to a .css file

I recomend you convert your xls(x) file with dreamweaver and then edit the html result with Sublime Text Editor [Available here](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Instead, use the following Excel formula to convert a sheet of data into a simple HTML table without any style:

```
    =CONCATENATE("<table>",CHAR(10),"<tbody>",CHAR(10),"<tr>",CHAR(10),"<th>",A1,"</th>",CHAR(10),"<th>",B1,"</th>",CHAR(10),"</tr>",CHAR(10),"<tr>",CHAR(10),"<td>",A2,"</td>",CHAR(10),"<td>",B2,"</td>",CHAR(10),"</tr>",CHAR(10),"...</tbody>",CHAR(10),"</table>")
```

Replace `A1` and `B1` with the column headers of your data, and `A2` and `B2` with the first row of your data. Repeat the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags as necessary for the rest of your data.

This formula concatenates together HTML tags and cell values to create a simple HTML table. Note that this formula assumes that the data is in columns A and B and that there are no blank cells in the data.

Once you have created the HTML code using this formula, you can copy and paste it into a plain text editor, save the file with an HTML extension (e.g. `table.html`), and open it in a web browser to see the table.