# How do I export Excel to HTML with inline CSS in VBA?

Tags: html, css, vba, excel

I have the following VBA which exports to HTML, but it puts `<style>` tags separate. I'd like to export to HTML with inline styles, suitable for email.

```
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     FileName:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

I saw no inline CSS option for this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823068.aspx

I found this online tool to do it manually: http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

This similar questions is not VBA related: [How to export Excel spreadsheet to HTML table with INLINE CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436370/how-to-export-excel-spreadsheet-to-html-table-with-inline-css)